# LocalReport.SubReportProcessing event is ignoring subsequent DataTables

Tags: c#, .net, reporting-services, reporting, rdlc

I have an (rdlc) report which contains a subreport within a table.  For each instance of the subreport that is generated the `LocalReport.SubreportProcessing` event is fired, which is in [agreement with the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.reporting.webforms.localreport.subreportprocessing%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

However for each of these events, it appears that only the **first DataTable assigned is used within the report**.  I can verify that  `ReportFactory.ReturnNextDataTable` is returning the appropriate DataTable for each row, but it appears the first instance of the DataTable is being repeated multiple times.

I've tried clearing out the report DataSources for each call (using `e.DataSources.Clear()`) but this makes no difference.

Here is my code:

```
void AddData(object sender, SubreportProcessingEventArgs e)
        {  
            DataTable merged = ReportFactory.ReturnNextDataTable;
            e.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource("RATES", merged)); //Subsequent DataTables ignored      
        }
```

I can't help feeling I'm going about this fundamentally the wrong way.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution :
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-PY/sqlreportingservices/thread/04f72cea-caea-48c5-82e9-f6b2b962717d

For me, the problem occurs after the migration from Report Viewer 9.0 (2008) to Report Viewer 11.0 (2012).

Comment: if you bring some of the specifics from that reference into the answer it will help answer

Answer (score 1):

In continuation to the answer of Stephane CLARISSE here is the extract from the source

> After some poking around and tinkering with my code, I found a workaround. The solution is to create a dummy parameter in the subreport, which you then need to bind to a field in the tablix dataset.  Any field will do as long as both the subreport parameter and the tablix dataset field are type-compatible.  You don't have to do anything with the parameter in the subreport, but now SSRS displays multiple instances of the same subreport, a separate one for each row in the tablix.

This seems to be a bug in SSRS and the workaround is to create a dummy paramaeter with any data type that is passed from the main report. Here is how it solved the problem for me

I added a dummy parameter in the subreport
[image: dummy parameter]

on the main report, I just passed any field for the dummy parameter that matches with the datatype of the dummy parameter. In my case, it is integer (eventID)

[image: main report properties]